# Why Athena JsonSerde field name mapping not working?

Tags: amazon-athena

According to the documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/create-tables-in-amazon-athena-from-nested-json-and-mappings-using-jsonserde/),

with this Athena table definition

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ctc.rets (
  `L_ListingID` string 
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'mapping.systemID' = 'L_ListingID'  
) 
LOCATION 's3://dmh.bucket/retsdata/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

I should get a column named `systemID`

Instead, I get:

[image]

Why is the column name mapping ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the table column name as `systemID`, then the mapping will resolve that column from the JSON attribute `L_ListingID`:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ctc.rets (
  `systemID` string 
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'mapping.systemID' = 'L_ListingID'  
) 
LOCATION 's3://dmh.bucket/retsdata/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```